# Updating intelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala-2.8

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 9.0 community edition. The Scala plugin I use uses Scala 2.7.6. How do I update the plugin for Scala 2.8? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the latest edition of IDEA (**9.0.3**) and the latest version of the scala plugin for that, this should be easy:

1. You need to [download the scala distribution for 2.8](http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads) to `$SCALA28_HOME`
2. To use scala, create a Java module and add the scala facet to it
3. During the addition process, you will be asked for a scala installation - point IDEA at your `$SCALA28_HOME` and it will automatically create `scala-library-2.8.0` and `scala-compiler-2.8.0` "global" libraries for you (it adds the *library* to your module as a dependency).

One thing to realize is that the embedded scala console (i.e. REPL) only seems to work if you add the *compiler* as a global library to the module as well.